# How to start Explorer on the Desktop folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I use Win+E, Explorer starts in the `Quick Access` location, which shows frequent folders and recent files.

Is there a way to make it start in the Desktop folder?

Comment: I suggest to use Autohotkey. See https://superuser.com/a/100611/471143

Answer (score 1):

I think with the Winkey+E shortcut, your options are limited to **Quick Access** or **This PC** (set via File Explorer options dialog).

You can create a shortcut via the **New > Shortcut** dialog with the target: **explorer shell:desktop**

Then you can assign a hotkey combo via the shortcut's **Properties** dialog.