# Bookmarking with subfolders in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, bookmarks

In Windows 7's Explorer I can favourite (bookmark) a folder, but I can't create categories (empty bookmark folders) to fill stuff into. **Same as putting the links into a browser's bookmark folders.**

Is there a way (or an app) to achieve this?

Comment: I don't have a Win7 system to check on, but it sounds like these folks may be talking about the same thing. Let me know if you found the answer you're looking for in here: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/171734-Sub-folders-in-Windows-Explorer-Favorites

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get tree organisation for Windows 7 file explorer favorites?](https://superuser.com/questions/72853/is-there-any-way-to-get-tree-organisation-for-windows-7-file-explorer-favorites)

Comment: @music2myear That's a question from 2009 with no real solutions.

Comment: It is the only solution. Windows doesn't have nested folders in the Favorites (or now Quick Access, which is a better name because it is less confusing). There are answers there with work arounds as well.

Comment: Also, using the term "categories" makes your question more confusing because you're not dealing with categories, you're dealing with folders and subfolders.

Comment: @music2myear I should change the title, you are right. The word "subfolders" didn't occur to me when I was thinking of a title.